# How do I revert a directory change in a PowerShell script when an uncaught exception is thrown?

Tags: powershell

In bash, if I wanted to change the current directory for a single command `do_thing`, I'd spawn a new subshell in which to change the directory, running

```
(cd folderName; do_thing)
```

The body of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474771/if-cmdlet-changes-current-directory-how-to-revert-it-back) suggests the way to do it in PowerShell is to use `Push-Location` to store the location, and `Pop-Location` after the command has finished running. This works, but is not ideal: I have to remember write `Pop-Location` at every return point of the script (e.g. before each exception, if it occurs while a location is pushed), and an uncaught exception will leave the current directory as is.

Is there a way to have the current directory reset to what it was at the start of the script, even if an uncaught exception is thrown?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`try...catch...finally` is the construct you're looking for!

This will allow you to handle your errors and perform a final action; whether the main try block was successful or not.

Here's a basic example:

```
try {
    $x = 1/0
}
catch {
    Write-Warning "An error occurred"
}
finally {
    Write-Output "This always runs"
}
```

More tailored to your situation:

```
Write-Output "BEFORE: $(Get-Location)"

try {
    Push-Location -Path "C:\temp\csv"
    Write-Output "DURING TRY: $(Get-Location)"
    $x = 1/0
}
catch {
    Write-Warning "An error occurred"
}
finally {
    Pop-Location
}

Write-Output "AFTER: $(Get-Location)"
```

Results:

> BEFORE: C:\temp
>
> DURING TRY: C:\temp\csv
>
> WARNING: An error occurred
>
> AFTER: C:\temp

Comment: In this case I do additionally want the error to be thrown, but it looks like `try {Push-Location ..; 1/0} catch {throw} finally {Pop-Location}` works for that. The idea here, if I have it correct, is just to wrap all the 'other directory' stuff in that sort of construct?

Comment: you can just omit the whole `catch` block @ChrisMidgley

Comment: It's safer to put `Push-Location` in the `try` block since it still pushes the current directory onto the stack even if it fails.

Answer (score 4):

Bash subshells are spawned as child processes, hence they don't modify the environment of their parent, whereas PowerShell (sub)expressions run within the same PowerShell process and thus do modify the environment of that process. To run PowerShell statements in a separate process you need something like `Start-Process` or `Start-Job`, e.g.

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Set-Location folderName
    do_thing
} | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

`Push-Location` and `Pop-Location` are equivalent to `pushd` and `popd` in bash.

Comment: these scriptblocks dont inherit any variables (which would be `export`able to a subshell in a bash-equivalent)